# Replace Dictionary Value with NewLine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dictionary, intellisense

I'm currently attempting to add custom tool tips as an extension to my Visual Studio.

However, upon hovering above the keyword, (because I have very long descriptions, I tried using \r\n but it clearly does not work and will appear as \r\n in the tool tip so I used)

```
//var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\xx\QuickInfo.csv"));
/*while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(',');
        //add in values in position 0 and 1 
        m_dictionary.Add(values[0], values[1].Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine));
    }*/
```

space

```
internal class VCLToolTipSource: IQuickInfoSource
{
    private VCLToolTipSourceProvider m_provider;
    private ITextBuffer m_subjectBuffer;
    private Dictionary<string, string> m_dictionary;
    public VCLToolTipSource(VCLToolTipSourceProvider provider, ITextBuffer subjectBuffer)
    {
        m_provider = provider;
        m_subjectBuffer = subjectBuffer;

        m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //CSV for Quick Info
        //var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\xx\QuickInfo.csv"));
        //For going through CSV positions 0,1//
        /*while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            //add in values in position 0 and 1 
            m_dictionary.Add(values[0], values[1].Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine));
        }*/

        //List of all tool tips//


        m_dictionary.Add("keyword", "value");
        m_dictionary.Add("adapt", " - Process given file  <br>Syntax: #adapt[(-samelevel|-continue|-samelevel-continue|-copy)][:] path [output-folder] [output-file]( vcl-command )*[#endadapt]<br>Variations:<br><br> -samelevel :  The scope of the adapted file will be raised to the current level which makes it possible to override variables<br> -continue  :  If the adaptable file is not found continue processing. (warning message instead of stop processing with error)<br>Note: #adapt-continue will open the file and process it. Unlike #adapt-copy.<br> -copy :  Instead of processing the file");
```

which is to replace all "<**br**>" with the Environment.Newline to shorten it.

However, now that I do not want to use a CSV file to import data, how to I read the data from the dictionary and replace <**br**> with a Newline??

Thank you

Comment: you want whole value to be replaced by new line ? or only <br> tag ?

Comment: Whenever <br> is tagged, I want a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is more along the lines of what you want to do?

```
m_dictionary = m_dictionary.ToDictionary(
                                k => k.Key, 
                                v => v.Value.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine));
```

This will go through the entire dictionary and replace any `"<br>"` values with `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: Hi yes, this is really close but it still appears as <br> ):

Comment: @leonardchan I tested this code before I posted the answer, and I confirm that it works as it should. Are you sure that you are looking at the output correctly?

Comment: Hi @Abion47 ok, my bad, something didn't sit well with visual studio restarting. Using your method works best and is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding yourstring.Replace("`<br>`", Environment.NewLine) at the end of the string.

```
m_dictionary
    .Add("adapt", 
         " - Process given file  <br>Syntax: #adapt[(-samelevel|-continue|-samelevel-continue|-copy)][:] path [output-folder] [output-file]( vcl-command )*[#endadapt]<br>Variations:<br><br> -samelevel :  The scope of the adapted file will be raised to the current level which makes it possible to override variables<br> -continue  :  If the adaptable file is not found continue processing. (warning message instead of stop processing with error)<br>Note: #adapt-continue will open the file and process it. Unlike #adapt-copy.<br> -copy :  Instead of processing the file"
    .Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "`<br>"` with `Environment.NewLine` or `\n`.

Code:

```
string str =  " - Process given file  <br>Syntax: #adapt[(-samelevel|-continue|-samelevel-continue|-copy)][:] path [output-folder] [output-file]( vcl-command )*[#endadapt]<br>Variations:<br><br> -samelevel :  The scope of the adapted file will be raised to the current level which makes it possible to override variables<br> -continue  :  If the adaptable file is not found continue processing. (warning message instead of stop processing with error)<br>Note: #adapt-continue will open the file and process it. Unlike #adapt-copy.<br> -copy :  Instead of processing the file";
   str =  str.Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine);
```

or

```
str =  str.Replace("<br>", "\n");
```

Output:
- Process given file
Syntax: #adapt[(-samelevel|-continue|-samelevel-continue|-copy)][:] path [output-folder] output-file*[#endadapt]
Variations:

-samelevel :  The scope of the adapted file will be raised to the current level which makes it possible to override variables
 -continue  :  If the adaptable file is not found continue processing. (warning message instead of stop processing with error)
Note: #adapt-continue will open the file and process it. Unlike #adapt-copy.
 -copy :  Instead of processing the file

Although my above answer run well in ideal cases, but you have to cover all the cases.

```
public string ReplaceBRwithNewline(string txtVal)  
{  
    string newText = "";  
    // Create Regex    
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex =   
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(<br />|<br/>|</ br>|</br>)");  
    // Replace new line with <br/> tag    
    newText = regex.Replace(txtVal, "\r\n");  
    // Result    
    return newText;  
}
```

I'm replacing here with `\r\n`, because on some browsers it works with `\n` and on some it works with `\r\n`.

Comment: But what I have is a dictionary, it is a bunch of dictionary items that needs to be added. 

m_dictionary.add("keyword, "value")

Comment: you can do that by foreach loop for all values in dictionary

Comment: but do you know how to use  m_dictionary.Add(values[0], values[1].Replace("<br>", Environment.NewLine)); instead? The "Environment.Newline" I tried to foreach but wasn't able to replace?

Comment: I did not get what exactly you want to do, can u please explain by simple example